# Efficiently store / compress an array of integers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, integer

I have a sorted array of unique random integers, with values 1<=x<=1,000,000,000.  What's the most space-efficient compression algorithm I can use to store them in a database?  I'm thinking maybe something involving bit fields..

Edit: The array is at most 1,000,000,000 in size.

Comment: You have a billion random integers? Or the array is a gigabyte in size?

Comment: like @ctide, I too am perplexed by this problem.  a sorted array of unique random integers in the range 1 to N in an array of size N...a[i] = i, so you can just use a function `def a(i); return i; end`?

Comment: Any chance you could supply more constraints on the data? A sorted array of from 4 to a billion completely random integers is quite a challenge to compress. Are they truly random, or are they constrained in some way? For instance, if the next item in a sorted array is always within 256 of the previous one, you could use just one byte to store the offset . . .

Comment: I agree. You have solutions below for non-sparse arrays, sparse arrays, and the full meal deal of one trillion sorted integers. There is no one solution that doesn't blow up in size under some conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `narray` for efficient handling of large numeric arrays in Ruby.

It is faster, and uses less memory. http://narray.rubyforge.org/

As for the DB storage part. It is possible to add marshalling to `narray` (which doesn't have it by default):

```
# This adds support for Marshal to NArray - found it at: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/194510
class NArray
  def _dump *ignored
    Marshal.dump :typecode => typecode, :shape => shape, :data => to_s
  end
  def self._load buf
    h = Marshal.load buf
    typecode = h[:typecode]
    shape = h[:shape]
    data = h[:data]
    to_na data, typecode, *shape
  end
end
```

. . . which will be quite efficient without you needing to write specific code.

If the numbers are completely random, there will be limits to what you can achieve with compression. Truly random data is pretty much incompressible.

If you have a good constraining model for how the numbers are arranged, then you can use knowledge of that to create a better compression ratio. The post suggesting to use a `Range` is an extreme example of that, but of course only works if you have a very simple structure.

If the structure is more or less arbitrary, just marshall the data and apply an of-the-shelf compression algorithm to it, like `zlib`.

Edit: The fact that the items are sorted lends itself to better compression. It also ticks a box for `narray` - it will sort numbers quicker than anything you can do manually with a Ruby `Array`

Sample code:

```
require 'narray'
require 'zlib'

# Ten thousand integers . . .
n = NArray.int(10000).random(100000).sort

# Compressed . . .
stored = Zlib::Deflate.deflate( Marshal.dump(n), 9 )

stored.length

 => 14297
```

That's not bad, 1.5 bytes per number (actual compression ratios will vary a lot, but you'll generally see less than 4 bytes per number using this technique)

Comment: Nice! But you example assumes a non-sparse array. NArray doesn't support sparse arrays, so it will take a lot of space to store a two element array with indicies of 1 and 900,000,000.

Comment: The OP hasn't asked for a sparse array, AFAICT. In fact, given that the array is sorted, it seems quite unlikely to me. However, it isn't 100% clear just what is being asked for, yet.

Comment: Yes. This sounds like one of those questions you toss out to a class to get them to realize that every solution has tradeoffs. Every time a proposal is put forward, the teacher adds a condition that blows up the solution. It can be fun!

Answer (score 1):

1..1,000,000,000 can be held in a 32bit integer. If the array is sparse, a reasonable encoding is to represent each valid element as 2 32bit integers, one being the element value and the other being the element index. You'd need 64 bits/2 integers for each valid element in the array, plus 32 bits/one integer to store the number of valid elements in the array.

Comment: +1 for simple approach sparesness, although the OP seems to want to allow for a very large range of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1e9 random unique integers in the range 1..1e9, in sorted order.  That means you have exactly one of each integer in the range.  Here's your best compression with ruby:

Store this:

```
"(1..10**9).to_a"
```

Then read it back and `eval` it.

Comment: The array is *at most* 1bn in size.

Comment: @ZacharyBurt The edit history shows _at most_ added three hours after my flip answer.  Fact is this is a terribly presented question with too many vague specifications and constraints and no hint as to purpose. Figure out how to say what your real problem is and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the size of your dataset.  How random-access does the data need to be?  Compressing it with bit fields might work, but you'll lose time decompressing the data, not to mention Ruby isn't as efficient as C working with such data.  Unless space is a **major** concern I'd just store it as a database in a table with a single integer field.

Comment: Updated with size.  Random access not necessary.

Comment: If they're sorted, and there's 1 billion items, in the range of 1 to 1 billion, doesn't that mean it's just 1..1 billion?  Why even store it?

Comment: There's <= 1 billion items.  There could be 4 items.